# How to match a certain number of digits recursively?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match occurrences of 6-digit numbers from the HTML output from an array of matched tags:

```
foreach (@name) {
        print $_->as_HTML =~ m/([0-9]*){6}/ . "\n";
};
```

What to do? This doesn't work, as you may notice.

---

Actually, I think I've got it:

```
foreach (@name) {
        print $_->as_HTML =~ m/[0-9]{6}/g;
        print "\n";
};
```

Comment: Does [`[0-9]{6}`](http://regex101.com/r/eO9gM5) work?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Same question. In this case, it could just be a nice word that rhymes with "repeatedly"...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the following:

```
my @numbers = $_->as_HTML =~ m/\d{6,}/g;
```

Pull all numbers that are 6 digits or longer from the document.